# jQuery flot with rotation plugin hides x axis labels

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to use jquery Flot to create a line chart with rotated x-axis labels and I can't.

I use this plugin https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor

and although x axis labels are rotated, some part is hidden.

[image]

seconds should be showing, too.

This is my options:

```
$.plot("#live-data",
        [{
            data: series,
        }],
        {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.5,
                    align: "center"
                },
                points:{
                    show:true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                ticks: x_ticks,
                rotateTicks: 45,
                labelWidth: 150,
                labelHeight: 150,
                reserveSpace: true
            },
            yaxis: {
                ticks: 10,
                min: 0,
                max: y_max,
                tickDecimals: 2
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: false
            }
        });
}
```

UPDATE: I add my HTML code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="block" style="height:550px">
            <div class="block-content" id="block-chart" style="height: 500px;">
                <h1>header</h1>
                <h3>sub-header</h3>
                <div id="live-data" style="width: 99%; height: 440px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [margin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) option to pad the sides of your chart to fix the cutoff axis labels:

> "margin" is the space in pixels between the canvas edge and the grid,
>   which can be either a number or an object with individual margins for
>   each side, in the form:
>
> ```
> margin: {
>     top: top margin in pixels
>     left: left margin in pixels
>     bottom: bottom margin in pixels
>     right: right margin in pixels
> }
> ```

To fix the issue, I set the bottom margin to 10:

```
grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: false,
    margin: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 10,
        right: 0
    }
}
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/2/) (no margin set), you can see that the second values in the axis labels are slightly cut-off on the bottom edge. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/1/), (set margin), the axis label text is not cut-off.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same results :-(. Maybe it is something wrong with my HTML code. Please, can you check my updated question?

Comment: @xpanta Did you try and modify the margin values to better suit your labels? I added your HTML code, the margin still works as expected ([JSFiddle without margin](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/3/) - [JSFiddle with margin](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/4/)). I'm using a time-based x-axis, your x-axis looks like a variable, it looks like you haven't included the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only difference that I see is that I don't use `jquery.flot.time` plugin. My x-axis are simple Strings. E.g. `["13:53", "13:55", ...]`. Do you thing that this might be the problem?

Comment: @xpanta after changing the axis to use defined strings, I still get the desired behavior: [without margin](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/8/) -- [with margin](http://jsfiddle.net/uujwz5vp/9/). Are you using the same versions of flot (and related plugins) that are in the fiddles?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my flot library and it now works. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from your link:

> The graph is resized so that all labels can be displayed properly.
>   - NOTE: currently this only works with label angle > 90 degrees.
>
> TODO:
>   - Fix plot resizing with long labels when angle < 90 degrees.  It seems to   require a y2axis at the moment and fails if one isn't defined.

So you could try 135 degrees instead of 45 for `rotateTicks` or adding a second y-axis.